# Upgrade visual studio, but still be able to use the old version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012

So, we would like to use VS 2012 for all new employees, but still have existing employees using VS 2008. Is it possible to do this without having to maintain two separate solutions and projects (one for each version)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with Visual Studio 2012 and VS 2010 Service Pack 1 (due to the [new Round Tripping feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2012/06/05/visual-studio-2012-compatibility-aka-project-round-tripping.aspx)), but not with older versions.  Opening a 2008 solution will require an upgrade to the newer formats.

Comment: You can even go back further.  TOOLS > Extensions & Updates > Online

Comment: @EricLeroy What are you talking about? I dont see any extensions that allow you to go back further.

Comment: I might have been mistaken.  If OP is talking about the actual VS UI, then I'm wrong.  If they are referring to .Net version, then yes.  On Visual Studio install, it asks you if you would like to make it compatible with older versions of VS, you can go back further than 2008.